# Avoid restart on orientation change for react native + android 12

Tags: android, react-native, orientation, restart

Problem -

My react-native app suddenly keeps restarting whenever I change the device orientation.
This was working 2 months back.

I started experiencing the problem after I upgraded my android version to v12, Build #SP1A.210812.016.

Here are my codes - AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
  android:name=".MainApplication"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
  android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
  android:allowBackup="false"
  android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
  android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
  android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
  <activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
  </activity>
</application>
```

MainActivity.java

```
      @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        SplashScreen.show(this);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
...
 @Override
      public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
           super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
           Intent intent = new Intent("onConfigurationChanged");
           intent.putExtra("newConfig", newConfig);
           this.sendBroadcast(intent);
      }
```

Please help if you have any idea what's causing this?

Thanks in advance!

using : "react-native": "0.64.1"

Comment: This problem does not exist in Android 10 using exactly the same code.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it.  For those who have encountered the same problem, try adding screenLayout to AndroidManifest.xml.  Code should look like this.

```
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode"
```

That solved the problem.