# Xamarin android app restarting on orientation change with newer android versions

Tags: android, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Our Xamarin android app is restarting whenever the device orientation is changed. We have configured the main activity with the following:

```cs
[Activity(Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
```

This seems to work with older Android versions such us Android 9 but with Android 12/13 devices the app restarts on orientation changes.

Any ideas why this is not working on newer Android versions?

Comment: According to [this native Android answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72298874/199364) adding `screenLayout` should fix it. I assume this would be `ConfigChanges.ScreenLayout` for Xamarin.

Comment: `ConfigChanges.UiMode` is the necessary value to fix the issue: [Answer on microsoft forums](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1163753/xamarin-android-app-restarting-on-orientation-chan?comment=question#newest-question-comment)

Comment: That forum answer also includes `ConfigChanges.ScreenLayout`. Both that and UiMode are recommended. You got it working? Please add an answer showing the exact line of code that worked for you.